# What is that in my red-eared slider's wound?

Tags: reptiles, turtles

**First Question**

I have taken a photo of her wound today (see the first figure below). You can see there is a dark pink thing. Does anyone know what it is? Is it pus or a scab?

**Second Question**

This wound has already been there for almost a month. I had taken her to a vet for consultation since I discovered it. The vet offered me some cream and iodine to apply at home and asked me to take her back for antibiotic injection every three days for about two weeks. After all the things, the vet told me it is healing and no need to go back but I doubt it. I have a picture of the wound a month ago (see the second figure). Can any tell me if the wound is really healing?

[image: Current condition of her right leg]

[image: Her right leg a month ago]

Comment: I just wanted to clarify since it looks like the picture at the bottom is the healed version of the photo on top. Is this correct or is the bottom one the before photo?

Comment: The bottom photo is the before photo while the upper photo is taken this week. The bottom photo looks as if it was healing but there was pus inside the whitened thin skin. Later the pus was squeezed out and the wound became a larger hole.

Comment: For those who are interested, my turtle has recovered from the wound. It seems that the upper figure does indicate a sign of healing.